# Close a specific Chrome tab using /bash

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome

So I have multiple in instances of Chrome opened to different sites with different profiles in chrome

```
#! /bin/bash
google-chrome --profile-directory=Default http://site1.com
google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile1 http://site2.com
google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile2 http://site3.com
google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile3 http://site4.com
```

is there a way i can close for ex only Profile 2 runing http://site4.com with out affecting the rest ? using a similar /bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closing chrome from terminal might not save profile details properly. You can install [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to close chrome tab with title as below:
    `wmctrl -c  window-title`

Comment: Thank you, that works great.

Comment: Can you accept the answer.

Comment: But if I have multiple profiles running the same site X  and same title when i run  wmctrl -c  window-title  it only closes one window and i wanted to close all the windows with the same title

Comment: ```wmctrl -x``` will add WM_CLASS to the output, if needed you could also customize WM_CLASS by adding flag ```--class=name``` to chrome